# Build several files in Maven Flex

Tags: apache-flex, maven, maven-plugin

I can use Maven with FlexMojos to generate swf file, but because I have several mxml files need to build, could I build them in 1 Maven pom file?

I know if I separate them into several projects, Maven can build them. But because these mxml files have some shared functions, it's not easy to manage if I separate them.

Another question is the size of swf file. The original file size build by Flex builder is about 80KB, but the file size by Maven is about 800KB. Is it normal?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds to me like a multi-module build which is exactly intended for such purposes.

```
+-- pom.xml
+-- module1
      +--- pom.xml
+-- module2
      +--- pom.xml
+-- common
      +--- pom.xml
```

I can recommend the [Sonatype book about this](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule.html).

Comment: Yes, I know it, I can separate them to several modules(projects). Actually, I already have about 10 modules, all of them are Java. I want to limit Flex inside 1 module only, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a sub-module which contains several flex modules...

```
+-- pom.xml
+-- module1
      +--- pom.xml
+-- module2
      +--- pom.xml
+-- module-flex
      +-- pom.xml
      +-- mod-flex-1
            +-- pom.xml
      +-- mod-flex-2
            +-- pom.xml
      +-- mod-flex-common
            +-- pom.xml
+-- common
      +--- pom.xml
```